# DynamicComponentLoader method LoadIntoLocation angular2rc1

Tags: typescript, angular

how to use method LoadIntoLocation with angular2 rc 001

in DynamocComponentLoader I have just two methods loadAsRoot and loadNextLocation

thanks

Comment: Check the [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37044960/1679310) for a plunker and some details

Answer (score 0):

`loadIntoLocation` was removed a while back. `DynamicComponentLoader` is deprecated anyway. Use `ViewContainerRef.createComponent()` instead.

For an example see [Angular 2 dynamic tabs with user-click chosen components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468)

Comment: It works well but it works as loadNextLocation but me I need somethings like loadIntoLocation add component inside <div>

Comment: As far as I know there is no way. You would need to add some element into the `<div>` that you then can use as target.